# Angular 7 minify assets with ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, minify

JavaScript and CSS files in `/assets` are not minified after `ng build --prod`. Does someone know how I can minify those files? I don't see anything in the angular doc.

Comment: The folder assets is copy as is. if you has a .css or .js NOT put in assets folder. this folder is only for images and files that you need -e.g. a .json that you read-

Comment: Most of external libs are in `architect.build.scripts` in `angular.json` but I have some .js files that should not be bundled with angular app. Scripts that are executed before angular for example. Where should a put these files ?

Comment: well, in the case the .js not use in Angular is correct (I referred to the others one -just create anoother folder and add the .js in angular.json, is a basic error include .css in assests folder and in angular.json -I don't want to say is your case-). I supose you always can minifier using external tools

Answer (score 4):

Everything you build in production are already minify if it not minify I think you havent turn on configuration in angular.json. You can use these config in your angular.json

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": true,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "serviceWorker": true,
        "deleteOutputPath": true,
        "budgets": [
            {
                "type": "initial",
                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then run `ng build --prod` again

Answer (score 1):

When you run `ng build --prod` angular-cli creates a new folder named `dist` in your project folder. the `dist` is the folder that you upload to your server in order to deploy your project.

the assets folder is not minimized because there is no code to minimize in that folder, angular-cli does not minimize images, svgs text files etc ...
if you want to minify images, you can search for online tools such as [TinyJPG](https://tinyjpg.com/)

> edit:

Not necessarily mean that you want to minimize your images, but in your `assets` folder there shouldn't be any files which are .js .css .html .ts etc...
only Jsons, images and other assets

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to minimize images, just .css and .js files.

Comment: So dont add .js and .css files to your assets folder

Comment: Most of external libs are in architect.build.scripts in angular.json but I have some .js files that should not be bundled with angular app. Scripts that are executed before angular for example. Where should a put these files ?

Comment: If you have a server, then you should load these scripts in the server before you load your angular app also you can load them in your index.html . i'm not so sure what are you trying to achieve of course but there are many ways to load js files. but just for this question, files within the assets folder will not get bundled with the angular app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack to minify the ts file:

Install webpack, webpack-cli, @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-typescript;

Add `webpack.config.js` to your project root folder:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [
  {
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    '@babel/preset-typescript'
                ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
    },
    entry: {
      main: './apps/js/some-file.ts'
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/js/'),
      filename: 'some-file.min.js'
    }
  }
];
```

In your build command, just add `& webpack --watch`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

When you run ng build --prod angular will create a new folder in your project called dist. the dist, This is the folder that you place on your server to run your application from.
You will see inside that folder, you will get a few files. All of your CSS and JS will be bundled and minified  into one file each

Answer (score 0):

`ng build` creates a build in the dist folder using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). The dist folder is published to your production website and contains everything needed to run your website (the minified Angular framework, your code, and dependencies referenced in the application).

CSS and JavaScript in the head of `index.html` will be referenced from your assets folder without minification. Consider [adding these files to your configuration](https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3) instead. The working files in the source folder are used for development purposes and are not modified during the build process.